# ASP.net Request Form empty string - Works only with old physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, request.form

I am currently taking over a project and trying to test a website on my machine locally.

I have the new and old project files ( old being a copy/backup, one being a git repository) in a parent folder.

I am trying to login on the website which does an AJAX post to an aspx page which handles it and posts backs to the page for redirects.

For some reason , with the new project , the Request.Form["email"] and password are all empty strings.

```
string tbxemail = (Request.Form["emailL"] == null) ? string.Empty : Request.Form["emailL"].ToString();
```

However , pasting over the old applicationhost.config into the new project works. Additionally, comparing the config files , only the physical paths are different

```
<site name="sitename" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Projects\sitename\sitename" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57905:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

The following change works (example names only):

```
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Projects\sitename\sitename oldversion" />
```

Other Things I have tried:
Command prompt : iisreset 
Deleting .vs folder or applicationhost.config
Configuring application pools (without publishing , these app pools do not seem to have any effect as they do not show my application running under any of them)

I have read somewhere that "Classic" managed pipeline causes Request.form not to work.

I just find it confusing that changing just the physical path in applicationhost.config resolves it ,BUT I know I shouldnt be using that path , especially since I dont know why it works just for the old project folder. I have compared all the files involved in the login process and they do not have any differences.

Help please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I needed to change the Web.config regarding the UrlRoutingHandler

```
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" ..................... />
```

Before that I just had

```
<remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
```